# Irvine x86 Assembly Output

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am learning assembly language using Kip Irvine's Library and i was trying to create a simple program which takes two integers as input and outputs their addition and subtraction, but I am having problem outputting them.

```
    include irvine32.inc
.data
    myMessage BYTE "Enter First Number: ",0Ah
    myMessage1 BYTE "Enter Second Number: ",0Ah
    myMessage2 BYTE "Addition: ",0Ah
    myMessage3 BYTE "Subtraction: ",0Ah
    num1 DWORD ?
    num2 DWORD ?
.code
main proc
    mov edx, offset myMessage
    call writestring
    call readint
    mov num1, eax
    mov edx, offset myMessage1
    call writestring
    call readint
    mov num2, eax
    mov eax, num1
    add eax, num2
    mov edx, offset myMessage2
    call writeint
    mov eax, num1
    sub eax, num2
    mov edx, offset myMessage3
    call writeint
exit
main endp
end main
```

Expected output:

> Enter First Number: 5
>   Enter Second Number: 3
>   Addition: +8
>   Subtraction: +2

but I am getting

[image: OUTPUT SS]

Comment: I don't know Irvine, but the strings must be terminated in some way. Try adding ",0" behind the strings, to tell the "WriteString" function where it stops

Comment: I also doubt that "writeInt" will print the string that EDX points to. use "writeString" to print the string (without newline in this case) and then afterwards call "writeInt"

Comment: @Tommylee2k thanks, I forgot to add call writestring after mov edx, offset myMessage. And i replaced ,0Ah with ,0,13h,10h and most of it got fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know irvine, but the manual is pretty much clear

This is probably what you wanted

```
    include irvine32.inc
.data
; the strings have to be terminated, so ",0" is added:
    myMessage BYTE "Enter First Number: ",0      
    myMessage1 BYTE "Enter Second Number: ",0
    myMessage2 BYTE "Addition: ",0
    myMessage3 BYTE "Subtraction: ",0
    myMessage3 BYTE 10,13,0
    num1 DWORD ?
    num2 DWORD ?
.code
main proc
    mov edx, offset myMessage
    call writestring
    call readint
    mov num1, eax
    mov edx, offset myMessage1
    call writestring
    call readint
    mov num2, eax

    ; addition, compose the line ( 3 parts: prompt, number, newline)
    mov edx, offset myMessage2
    call writestring
    mov eax, num1
    add eax, num2
    call writeint
    mov edx, offset newLine    ; add a CrLF here
    call writestring


    ; subtraction
    mov edx, offset myMessage3
    call writestring
    mov eax, num1
    sub eax, num2
    call writeint
    mov edx, offset newLine
    call writestring

exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it figured out. Thanks anyways